# cant set display to full resolution (1920*1080)

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I've two monitors, they support different resolutions and they were working just fine until a few days ago.
In the mean time I installed some software (e.g. Virtual Box) and after restarting the PC, one of them (higher resolution was not longer supported with max. resulutions- 1920*1080.
Now the maximum I can use on that display is 1440*900, if I change to a higher resulotion, the monitor does not get signal (black).

I don't know what I can do, there are no drivers I can use in 'additional drivers'. 
Could it be something in the BIOS?

*cvt -r 1920 1080* returns:

`# 1920x1080 59.93 Hz (CVT 2.07M9-R) hsync: 66.59 kHz; pclk: 138.50 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080R"  138.50  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1111 +hsync -vsync`

**xrandr**

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1024, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 270mm
   1280x1024     60.02*+  75.02  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-0 connected 1280x1024+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +
   1280x1024     60.02* 
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      70.07    60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   640x480       66.67    60.00  
   720x400       70.08
```

**The command:** `xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60`
turns my screen black saying "*no signal*"

What could be the problem?